# Why after i've converted a powershell script into an .exe it doesn't work anymore?

Tags: powershell

i have a script that import a session from exchange server to use some Exchange cmdlets.

If i run the script .ps1 it works correctly but after i convert it to an .exe with ps2.exe it prompt me out some weird error.

[image]

The code lines reference to are the following:

```
$addressbook.Name = $addressbook.Name | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName –ne ("All Users")} 
$addressbook.Name = $addressbook.Name | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName –ne ("All Contacts")} 
$addressbook.Name = $addressbook.Name | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName –ne ("All Rooms")} 
$addressbook.Name = $addressbook.Name | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName –ne ("Public Folders")} 
$addressbook.Name = $addressbook.Name | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName –ne ("All Distribution Lists")}
```

Can someone help me fix this out ?

Comment: looks like it somehow corrupts the `-` in the process.. are there any other places in the script where it works?

Comment: Yes it works in these lines : 
- If ($Name -ne "")
- If ($Credentials.UserName -ne $UserName)

It does not prompt me any errors here.

Comment: Looks like either your code there doesn't have actual hyphens in the operators, or the conversion changes them.

Comment: `–ne` should be `-ne`. You have a weird hyphen in there.

Comment: What are you using to convert them? I use pstoexe and it works fine :)

Comment: I use PS2EXE-GUI to convert scripts. I'll try pstoexe and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: @Theo It's an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash), not a hyphen.

Comment: `-replace '\p{Pd}','-'` on all the lines before running ps2exe :)

Comment: Yes actually as you mentioned they wasn't real hypen but they was en dash. Probably i copied those lines from some bad code lines on some forum. After i changed them everything works fine. Thanks!.